# Define the label number in blogger xml

Tags: xml, label, blogger

Is it possible to get one of the many labels of a post with `<data:post.labels>` or `<data:label.name>` in blogspot.

Eg: There are total 5 labels in a post but i want only the 3th label to be displayed. I tried this :

```
<data:post.labels[3]/>

or 

<data:label[3].name/>
```

Any suggestions are appreciated!

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use b:eval tag

```xml
<b:eval expr="data:post.labels[0].name" />
```

Comment: Thanks very much! You're the best!